# product quantity updating backend issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman, e-commerce, mern

iam trying to update my product quantity ny id but its not working.Iam building an ecommerce app in mernstack, so iam implementing the backend first.i used a similar update function for updating product details and its working ,so now iam testing using postman and its sending request and hanging,in vs code no errors or the put the request iam sending is not showing,i tried console.log at various points

```
    //stock number update
    import productModel from "../models/productModel.js";


    export const updateProductStockController = async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const { productId } = req.params;
    const { quantity } = req.body;
    
    // Validate if the provided quantity is a positive number
    if (quantity <= 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Quantity must be a positive number' });
    }
    
    // Find the product by ID and update the quantity
    const product = await productModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
    productId,
    { $set: { quantity: quantity } },
    { new: true }
    );
    
    if (!product) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Product not found' });
    }
    
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Product quantity updated successfully', product });
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Error while updating product quantity' });
    }
    };

here is the product route

    router.put('/stock-update/:pid',requireSignIn,isAdmin,formidable(),updateProductStockController)

here is the server main route

    app.use("/api/v1/products", productRoutes);

tried console log at various points,tried asking chatgpt
```